# JavaScript object destructuring and aliasing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, alias

Is there a way to destructure an object in JavaScript and alias the local destructured object?

Something like:

```
const env = {ENV_VAR_X, ENV_VAR_Y, ENV_VAR_Z} = process.env;
```

...and have `env` become a local constant containing those selected environment variables. (I'm aware that my example doesn't work with babel)

```
{
  ENV_VAR_X: "s867c7dsj4lal7", 
  ENV_VAR_Y: "hd73m20s-a=snf77f", 
  ENV_VAR_Z: "production"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this aliasing?

On a side note, I'm using babel as my transpiler, then running the script with node so that I can leverage more ECMAScript 6 functionality.

Comment: Works for me in FF Nightly.. https://gist.github.com/liam4/393863561cb20e1b90b0

Comment: That's awesome and unfortunate at the same time! Using babel6, it doesn't though :( 

I'd like an example to target that.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really possible with destructuring until babel fixes that.. :(

Comment: It also doesn't work with node latest :(
Looks like I'll have to take the verbose route.

Comment: Also works with Chrome canary :|

Comment: Sadly an invalid left side assignment using `node --harmony_destructuring` :i

Comment: I've added a feature request to babel's issue tracker. Hopefully it can be fixed soon enough. There's no only way to achieve this without essentially writing a double assignment, one for the destructured object and one for the aliased object?

Comment: It sounds so. Great that an issue is being tracked now though.

Comment: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7130

Comment: Can you point to the relevant portion of the spec which defines what this is supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm not certain if it's part of the spec. I did not read the white papers regarding destructuring. However, I am wondering if/how this can be accomplished.

Comment: This is an incorrect duplicate. This question should be re-opened.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to my reading of the spec, this should be parseable, but it doesn't mean what you think. It would be parsed from right-to-left as

```
const env = ({ENV_VAR_X, ENV_VAR_Y, ENV_VAR_Z} = process.env);
```

where the production

```
({ENV_VAR_X, ENV_VAR_Y, ENV_VAR_Z} = process.env)
```

is defined, like all other assignments, as **evaluating to the RHS**, which is `process.env`.

Therefore, your code is equivalent to

```
(/* global */ {ENV_VAR_X, ENV_VAR_Y, ENV_VAR_Z} = process.env);
const env = process.env;
```

It's quite easy to validate this:

```
const foo = {a: 1, b: 2};
const bar = {a} = foo;
```

results in a new constant `a` being declared with the value `1`, as you would expect. However, the value of `bar` is **not** an "alias to the deconstructed object", which would be `{a: 1}`; it's the same as `foo`, which is `{a: 1, b: 2}`. `bar === foo`.

---

What you are trying to do has been discussed many times here on SO and also in the ES discuss group. The bottom line is that there is no way to do this. All you can do is:

```
const {ENV_VAR_X, ENV_VAR_Y, ENV_VAR_Z} = process.env;
const env = {ENV_VAR_X, ENV_VAR_Y, ENV_VAR_Z};
```

In other words, there is no way to "deconstruct from an object into an object", or "pick from an object into an object". You can only deconstruct from an object into variables.

You could fall back to the old-fashioned way:

```
const env = {ENV_VAR_X: process.env.ENV_VAR_X, ...
```

which I know is horrible.

You could use the `pick` function from underscore or write your own, but that requires you to say

```
const env = _.pick(process.env, 'ENV_VAR_X', "ENV_VAR_Y', 'ENV_VAR_Z');
```

which is only slightly less horrible.

We have ["rest properties" and "spread properties"](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) proposed for ES7, but they do not seem to help us here.

---

What we need is a new syntax for picking properties into another object. There have been various proposals made for this, none of which has gained much traction. One is the "extended dot notation", which allows a curly-bracketed construct to be put after a dot. In your case, you would write

```
const env = process.env.{ENV_VAR_X, ENV_VAR_Y, ENV_VAR_Z};
                       ^^
```

You can find out more about this proposal [here](https://github.com/rtm/js-pick-notation/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Gotcha. So this is not possible at all? My only option is to either a) deal with the entire object being assigned to the local variable `bar`, or b) define a new variable containing the desired properties from the target object?

Comment: "results in a new constant `a` being declared with the value 1," --- `a` would not be declared, since there is no declaration for it in that statement.

Comment: Dangerous error at "Therefore, your code is equivalent to […]": the `ENV_VAR_*` variables become global, not `const`. Proof: `(function() { const a = {x} = {x: 1}; })(); console.log(window.a === undefined && window.x === 1);  // true`.

Comment: Given that the answerer had deleted their account, I took the liberty to convert the statement mentioned in @wchargin's comment to one with an inline `/* global */` comment (still valid syntax).

Answer (score 10):

To find assigning a new name to a destructed value, just use this:

```
obj = {x: 10, y: "Something"};
const { x: otherName } = obj;
```

Comment: While this is true, that's not what the question was asking. Which you're referencing is already asked/answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065418/1842294. My case was wondering if there's a feature in the language for picking properties from one object to a new object.

Comment: To copy all properties of an object to another object use `let newObject = {...fromObject};` or simply `var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);` or an old-fashioned way `var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: That's cloning an object :). The question is to specifically pick certain properties from one object to a new object, which natively requires a two step process.

Comment: OK, I didn't get your question but If you are using TypeScript then I think the `Pick` utility type is your answer

Comment: That utility type helps to express the shape of the object I want, but not the actual operation of picking the values to that object at runtime. I have to leverage the approaches mentioned in the accepted answer to achieve the runtime functionality.