# Destructuring and rename property

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, rename, destructuring

```
const a = {
 b: {
  c: 'Hi!'
 }
};

const { b: { c } } = a;
```

Is it possible rename `b` in this case? I want get `c` and also rename `b`.

Comment: What do you mean by "rename"? The `a.b` property has the name `b`, and you can't change that. What is the desired result?

Comment: @Bergi like `const { b: d } = a` but also with get `c`.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You could destructure with a renaming and take the same property for destructuring.

```js
const a = { b: { c: 'Hi!' } };
const { b: formerB, b: { c } } = a;

console.log(formerB)
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the property can be repeated in destructuring.

Comment: but you cannot do this while destructuring arrays can you?

Comment: @RegarBoy, do you have an example?

Answer (score 62):

You can destructure the same property multiple times, onto different targets:

```
const { b: {c}, b: d } = a;
```

This assigns `a.b.c` to `c` and `a.b` to `d`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also correct, but @NinaScholz answered a little earlier.

Comment: I like this one, more concise.