# How to destructure nested data returned from useQuery?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have an Apollo query:

```js
const { error, loading, data: user } = useQuery(resolvers.queries.ReturnUser, {
    variables: { userId: parseInt(id) },
  });
```

The data object returned from the query has another object called `returnUser`. So the actual object is:

```js
data: {
  returnUser: {
    name: 'Some Name'
  }
}
```

In my JSX I want to output the data:

```
return (
  <div>
    { user ?
      <p>Profile {user.returnUser.name}</p> :
      <div>User not found</div> }
  </div>
);
```

As you can see I need to access the `returnUser` object on the `user` object to get the actual user data. This is not great. Is there any way to destructure the `data` object from the `useQuery` so I can assign the nested object to `user`?

//edit: While this looks like a duplicate question, the answer is different due to the async nature of `useQuery`. If you don't set a default value you'll get an error.

Comment: I would probably `const {returnUser: user} = data;` This assigns the value of `data.returnUser` to `const user` and allows you to use `user.name`, `user.someProp` see: [Destructuring and rename property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065348/destructuring-and-rename-property)

Comment: Sure, but wouldn't it be nice if it could be done in a single line? :)

Comment: `const { error, loading, data: { returnUser: user } } = useQuery...`

Comment: Btw it's `.name` not `.user_name`

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer thanks to @Pilchard:

```
const {error, loading, data: {returnUser: user} = {}} = useQuery(resolvers.queries.ReturnUser, {
    variables: {userId: parseInt(id)},
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same nesting while deconstructing the data.

e.g.

```
const data = {
  anotherLevel: {
     returnUser: {
      name: 'Some Name'
    } 
  }
}

const { anotherLevel: {returnUser: { name }}} = data;

console.log(name); // prints Some Name
```