# 'string' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, react-functional-component

Trying to learn some Typescript and have encountered an error early. I'm getting quite a few errors although I'm following a tutorial. I have commented out the errors I'm receiving. If someone could please explain why they are occurring, and how to fix them that would be fantastic.

```
import React from "react";

interface IProps {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    title: string;
}

let Customer: React.FC<IProps> = ({
    name: string,
    //'string' is declared but its value is never read.
    age: number,
    title: string,
    //'string' is declared but its value is never read.
}) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h2>Customer Component</h2>
            <ul className="list-group">
                <li className="list-group-item">Name: {name}</li>
                {/* //This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746) */}
                {/* 'name' is deprecated.ts(6385) */}
                {/* lib.dom.d.ts(17329, 5): The declaration was marked as deprecated here. */}
                <li className="list-group-item">Age: {age}</li>
                {/* Cannot find name 'age'. */}
                <li className="list-group-item">Title: {title}</li>
                {/* Cannot find name 'title'. */}
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Customer;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let Customer: React.FC<IProps> = ({
    name: string,
    //'string' is declared but its value is never read.
    age: number,
    title: string,
    //'string' is declared but its value is never read.
}) => {
```

`IProps` is the interface where you define all your properties with specific types. Right side you use that as a variable. You're destructing the object so just define the names like `{name, age, title}`.

If you use `name: string` on the right side, you renamed the `name` as `string`. The field `name` is taking from libraries that is why you got that error. On the second line, there is no `age` variable as you renamed it to `number`.

This is the updated code.

```
import React from "react";

interface IProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  title: string;
}

let Customer: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  name,
  age,
  title,
}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2>Customer Component</h2>
      <ul className="list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item">Name: {name}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item">Age: {age}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item">Title: {title}</li>
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Customer;
```

You can read [Object Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [renaming the destructured fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065348/destructuring-and-rename-property)

Comment: I see, I think on the tutorial he has it set up so it shows the type of the props next to it. Thanks for your help.